# Django Celery Periodic Task at specific time

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using `celery==4.1.1` in my project. In my `settings.py`, I have the following:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1"


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'mathematica.core.tasks.another_test',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=45, hour=00)
    },
    'task-number-two': {
        'task': 'mathematica.core.tasks.test',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='*/1')
    }
}
```

The second task mentioned in `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` is running perfectly. However, the first task `mathematica.core.tasks.another_test` which is a simple function returning a string is not running at the specified time, `00:45 (45 minutes past midnight)`. I have tried a number of ways to run a function at a given time each day but failed to achieve the same.

Please suggest ways/hints to achieve the same results.

Comment: So you only have issues with scheduled tasks if they are set for a specific day or time?

Comment: Yes. The Issue is only occurring when i want to run a function at a specific time of the day.

Answer (score 2):

```
'automatic_daily_report': {
            'task': 'tasks.daily_reports',
            'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=0),
            'args': None
        }


@shared_task()
def daily_reports():
    print("Mid- Night")
```

Above code worked for me.

Comment: Is it a periodic task? Does it run everyday at midnight?

Comment: Yes, it runs every day at midnight.