# How to send a message over websocket at a certain time

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am new to websockets and have just now gotten a working websocket connection in my application. I am trying to have the server check once per minute in the database to find upcoming tournaments, and for each player connected to a websocket that is registered in a tournament starting that minute, send a message that tournament with ID xxxxx is starting now. I have the following

tournaments/consumers.py:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class TournamentLobbyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        print("The websocket received a message: '%s'" % message)
```

tournaments/routing.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url('ws/tournaments/$', consumers.TournamentLobbyConsumer),
]
```

tournaments/templates/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Tournament Lobby</title>
</head>

<script>
    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/tournaments/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        // var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        // var message = data['message'];
        alert("message received from websocket")
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
</script>

{% if tournaments %}

  <ul>
    {% for tournament in tournaments %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'tournament_detail' tournament.id %}"> {{ tournament.name }} {{ tournament.start_time }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}

  <p>No tournaments are available</p>

{% endif %}



</html>
```

When I go to this tournament lobby, I get the message on the server that a "websocket handshake" has taken place. So the websocket connection is working. I am confused now as to how to run a loop on the running server which checks every minute for new tournaments and then sends the message to these connected clients. The tutorials I've done only show a server responding to client requests, but a websocket should be able to go in either direction.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for scheduling your jobs. Your code would looks like this:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(check, 'cron', second='*/60')
scheduler.start()

# Function to run every 60 seconds
def check():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first call the consumer method in charge of sending the notification (channel)
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html (Using Outside Of Consumers)

```
import channels.layers
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

def SimpleShipping(data, **kwargs):

  group_name = 'notifications'
  channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()

  async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
    group_name,
    {
      'type': 'notify_event',
      'data': data,
      # other: data,
    }
  )
```

declare the method in the consumer (add consumer to the notification channel)

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class TournamentLobbyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

  room_group_name = 'notifications'

  def connect(self):
    # Join room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
      self.room_group_name,
      self.channel_name
    )

    self.accept()

  def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
      self.room_group_name,
      self.channel_name
    )

  # Receive message from WebSocket
  def receive(self, text_data):
    # ...
    pass

  # Receive message from room group (notifications)
  def notify_event(self, event):
    data = event['data']
    # Send message to WebSocket
    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
      'data': data,
    }))
```

now you must choose the method for background tasks (Celery is recommended http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)
(look at this question [Django Celery Periodic Task at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649919/django-celery-periodic-task-at-specific-time))

```
from projectname.appname.modulename import SimpleShipping

@shared_task()
def daily_reports():
  # Run the query in the database.
  # ...
  data = { 'results': 'results' }
  # notify consumers (results)
  SimpleShipping(data)
```

note: I hope it helps, since the task you want to implement is quite extensive, and you should not take it lightly, although this summary will allow you to see the flow of data